# possible socket.io memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, redis, socket.io

Using socket.io 0.9.17 with a redis store, over time the memory usage grows from ~150mb at startup to beyond 1.0gb.

I took 2 heap snapshots using [node-heapdump](https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump). One after app start and another a day later. And compared the results and it looks like the biggest offender is string objects.

Below are the screenshots of the comparison.

[image]

When I expand the string objects all I see is some trace and a uncaughtException.

[image]

The app doesn't crash and there are no exceptions when running the same code on dev environments. These strings are events that are passed to socket.io and distributed to the nodes via the redis store. The relevant code for this is below

```
var result = {
        posts: [postData],
        privileges: {
            'topics:reply': true
        },
        'reputation:disabled': parseInt(meta.config['reputation:disabled'], 10) === 1,
        'downvote:disabled': parseInt(meta.config['downvote:disabled'], 10) === 1,
    };

for(var i=0; i<uids.length; ++i) {
    if (parseInt(uids[i], 10) !== socket.uid) {
        websockets.in('uid_' + uids[i]).emit('event:new_post', result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading to socket.io 1.x got rid of the memory leak.